# Strange Behaviour on Lottie Animation View

Tags: android, xml, flutter, kotlin, lottie

so I have splash screen with Lottie animationView with xml files like below

But IDE says

```
Cannot resolve class com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
```

The thing is I can run my app in debug and Splash content showing content perfectly
when I want to build in release version It cant because Error: LottieAnimationView must extend android.view.View [Instantiatable]

Iam following Official doc listed in here [official lottie doc](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android)
and there nothing wrong and Splash is showing in debug version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/splash_cat"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_speed="1.00" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

edit1: iam using flutter and follow this example [flutter Lottie Splash](https://medium.com/swlh/native-splash-screen-in-flutter-using-lottie-121ce2b9b0a4)

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Part One :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/progressAnimationView"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="196dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.553"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="splash_cat.json"    
            app:lottie_loop="true" />


      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Part Second :**
Now in the program code section, you can see the address of your animation file again in this way

> IN MainActivity

```
        private LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;  //global define 
        .
        .
        .
```

> in onCreate() //Activity  or onCreateView Fragment

```
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.progressAnimationView);
        lottieAnimationView.setAnimation(R.raw.splash_cat);
```

Comment: where I can put that ? 
this is my splashView.kt 


~import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreen


class SplashView : SplashScreen {
    override fun createSplashView(context: Context, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.splash_view, null, false)

    override fun transitionToFlutter(onTransitionComplete: Runnable) {
        onTransitionComplete.run()
    }
}~

Comment: You do not want to write the second part, test it with the same XML codes that I put

Comment: I try that in my main activity but cant input it because that is java code and my android studio force me to refactor it

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this, what i did is re-implement the latest lottie version and gradle, then clean project and rebuild project.

Comment: my Lottie version is 4.0.0(latest) and since 3.7.0 still ecountering this error 
I will try to clean project

Comment: Have you tried adding . maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }  . in your build .gradle project?

Comment: no the problem is not in locating the package but android studio want me to instantiate that class